# Can we fix/synonymize the tags on MSO that refer to "Stackoverflow" instead of "Stack Overflow"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, meta

There are a few tags on MSO that use the wrong spacing for "Stack Overflow" (and "Stack Exchange"):

- [stackoverflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams) -> [stack-overflow-for-teams](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-for-teams)
- [stackoverflow-app](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-app) -> [stack-overflow-app](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-app)
- [stackoverflow-talent](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-talent) -> [stack-overflow-talent](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-talent)
- [stackoverflow-business](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-business) -> [stack-overflow-business](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-business)
- [portuguese-stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/portuguese-stackoverflow) -> [portuguese-stack-overflow](/questions/tagged/portuguese-stack-overflow)
- [stackexchange-button](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-button) -> [stack-exchange-button](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-button)
- [stackexchange-openid](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-openid) (this should actually probably be merged with [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) as there are only two questions on this version and 20+ on the plain [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) tag) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It seems that searching "stack-overflow" in tags (or "stackoverflow") will return both options, so this would be more an appearance fix than a functional one.

Even considering that, I think that it's an important consideration that the flagship network site should use the proper spacing for its own site/network name.

I'm recommending that all of these tags should be merged with or synonymized to a version with the correct spacing.

Comment: I doubt if *wrong spacing* warrants adding those proposed synonyms. We're going to look like the hyphen-site ...

Comment: Officially it is "stack overflow" with a space. Therefore, a hyphen is recommended

Comment: minor blemish, but makes sense.

Comment: One reason _not_ to add the hyphen, is that [tag:stack-overflow] already exists and refers to the error, not the site.

Comment: @HongOoi but that's on main, not meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Trademark Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> Stack Overflow is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters).

Therefore it completely makes sense that there needs to be a hyphen.

All of them are renamed now. In order to not break the feeds of any Stack Overflow developers who are following those specific tags, I've added the present tags as synonyms as well.